# How to check amount of data available for a socket in C and Linux

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I have a server that receives a continuous stream of data. As opposed to reading multiple times from a socket, I would like to read the entire data in socket receive buffer with one system call to `read()`.

Of course I can pass a large buffer and `read()` will try to fill it with all available data. But this would waste a lot of memory as most of the times the malloc'ed buffer would be bigger than actual data available on socket. Is there a way to query the available data on a socket?

Comment: There's really not a good way to do this -- due to message fragmentation on the sender's side, you may not receive one complete application-level message at once.  The proper way to do this is to `select()` and then `read()` a chunk of some size from the socket, and then see if you have a complete message.  If so, remove that message from the buffer and process it.  Then go back to `select()`.

Comment: i purposefully did not introduce notion of a message. My question is related to simply reading whatever data was available at the time of the read like system call.

Comment: Then the answer is "keep calling `read()` until `select()` with a timeout of zero (not NULL) returns an empty read-ready list.

Comment: that results in multiple system calls to select

Comment: It's unclear to me why that's a problem.

Comment: Why is "wasting" memory a concern? You said this was a server, and servers these days have lots of memory.  For server code, it's usually more efficient to just allocate a "large enough" buffer once on startup than to keep reallocing it for each new blob of data.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Yes:

```
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

...

int count;
ioctl(fd, FIONREAD, &count);
```

Comment: fizzer, I tried this and ioctl seems to return the number of bytes on the socket, but not the number of messages.  Is there a way to get the number of messages or am I reading this value incorrectly?  Thanks!

Comment: There's not really such a thing as 'messages' at the TCP layer, just a stream of bytes.  Your application is responsible for imposing any additional structure.

Comment: Is this portable? Is this part of BSD Sockets?

Answer (score 6):

No, there is not. Even if there were a way to do this, any answer you get would be immediately out of date (because new data may arrive at any time).

Note that when you pass a buffer to `read()`, the function will return when there is *any* amount of data to read (at least one byte), instead of waiting for the buffer to completely fill.

Comment: +1.  Also, you almost certainly do not want this anyway.  Processing data in cache-friendly-sized chunks (few kilobytes) is almost always faster than processing huge chunks.

Comment: I agree. Although I would add that I think that passing a reasonably large buffer to read() wouldn't be a bad idea. Also, you could allocate a larger buffer, read a bit, store it into the larger buffer and then read a bit more. But it will only mean that the processing takes longer once you do process it.

Comment: @Nemo how is it efficient to do multiple reads in order of few KB, if the socket have 20MB of data queued to be read as opposed to one system call to drain 20MB? Also what cache are you referring to? L1, L2? OR Are you implying the buffer size should be a multiple of page size ?

Comment: @MatsPetersson you could do with some sort of circular buffer, provided it has adequately space. Multiple readers can process the buffer, providing parallelism.

Comment: If you REALLY have megabytes of data sitting waiting, then you should try reading a larger buffer. But your message says that "if I pass a large buffer, it's a waste of space". Obviously, these things are rather a compromise. If SOMETIMES you have lots of data, you have to accept that SOMETIMES you have to pass a large buffer. If you mostly have very little data, then you obviously will eventually catch up and run out of data. But memory is pretty cheap these days [except if you want 32 or 64GB sticks, but 16 or 32GB is achievable for around $50-100 per stick]

Comment: Greg, that is why i mentioned that read will try to fill it with all the "available" data in the socket, provided i provide a big enough buffer to read.

Comment: @Jimm: I was thinking L1 ("few kilobytes"), but the principle applies in general.  Even if all you are doing is filling a large in-memory buffer, doing it via small reads will be no slower because you can keep overwriting data in the L1 cache (read into small buffer, copy somewhere else, read into same small buffer again, etc.)  But you are presumably going to do _something_ with the data, and my point is that you are better off doing that something on small chunks (fresh in the cache) than large chunks (stale, need to be fetched from RAM).  TLB miss penalty also favors small buffers.

Comment: @Mats: It is worse than you think, I think.  In general, reading and processing 1000 8K chunks is much faster than reading one 8 meg chunk and then processing it.  This is true whether you are doing a calculation (e.g. taking the average) or just moving the data around (e.g. writing to disk or to another socket).  Of course there are exceptions, but in my experience most programmers massively underestimate the performance impact of locality in modern systems.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Non-bloking sockets](http://www.kegel.com/dkftpbench/nonblocking.html), or select()/poll() for that matter. I prefer non-blocking sockets because I can do other things while waiting for new data.

Answer (score 3):

This is a "sort of" answer: `recv(char* buffer, size_t nytes, int flags)` where flags is OR'ed with:

```
MSG_PEEK
This flag causes the receive operation to return data from the beginning of the receive queue without removing that data from the queue. Thus, a subsequent receive call will return the same data.
```

Such that you can see if an arbitrary number of bytes exists in the buffer, without irreversibly reading the buffer.   This is a half-answer because it is not  the most efficient way to do this, and MSG_PEEK is usually employed when messages have known length headers maybe like this:

```
000123DT001
```

where `00123` is the length of the whole message including header, `DT` is the type of message, and `001` is the number of retries by the sender. The idea is that you can fetch something that tells you how many bytes make a complete read of a message.  You are not interested in messages.  But that is the reason behind `MSG_PEEK`

Answer (score 1):

You have to try send and receive command as well as you are able to read and write in socket character by character so no wastage of memory and even better communication.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are trying to get many packets with single system call to reduce the overhead due to system calls.

so u can try **PACKET sockets interfaces for linux 2.4 or 2.6+ kernels** try this http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/networking/packet_mmap.txt